# Second-Order ODE with a Change of Variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I'm a bit stuck on a homework problem laid out by my professor. It's a relatively standard 2nd order ODE, but she's asked us to use a change of variable to solve it, which is throwing me off quite a bit. The problem is as follows.

$$
xy'' + 2y' + xy  =0, y(\pi ) = -1, y'(\pi ) = 2
$$

The change of variables provided is

$$
u=xy
$$

Any help at all as to how to go about this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$ u=xy\implies u'=y+xy' \implies u''=2y' +xy'' $$

so your DE becomes ...

$$ u''+u=0; u(\pi)=-\pi, u'(\pi)=2\pi - 1
$$

Comment: Where do you 'substitute back'? I've obtained a general form for u, but I'm getting stuck on how to transfer that back to an equation involving x and y.

Comment: $y(x)$ is simply $u(x)/x$.